# Para qué funciona .getSelectedIndex() en un JComboBox en Java?

Tags: java

Para qué funciona `.getSelectedIndex()` usado en un `JComboBox` en Java?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como su nombre lo indica, el método [getSelectedIndex()](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/javax.swing/JComboBox/0900__JComboBox.getSelectedIndex_.htm) se usa para obtener el indice del elemento seleccionado dentro del [JComboBox](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html).

Como ejemplo, teniendo los elementos `"Bird", "Cat", "Dog", "Rabbit", "Pig"` en tu JComboBox :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

puede obtener el indice de cada elemento mediante [getSelectedIndex()](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/javax.swing/JComboBox/0900__JComboBox.getSelectedIndex_.htm), si seleccionas "Pig", obtendrás el valor del indice que sería 4, recordemos que los indices inician con el valor 0.

---

De la documentación:

> [getSelectedIndex()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#getSelectedIndex--):   Devuelve un número entero que especifica el elemento de la lista
>   actualmente seleccionada, donde 0 especifica el primer elemento de la
>   lista; O -1 si no se selecciona ningún elemento o si el elemento
>   seleccionado actualmente no está en la lista.